# White screen appears instead of splash screen

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

While running my application in iOS device, instead of splash screen a white screen appears.
`ionic cordova resources` command had been used, even after that this issue occurs

Version details:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.10.3 (/Users/akashb/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 29 other plugins)

System:

   ios-sim : 8.0.2
   NodeJS  : v14.17.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm     : 6.14.13
   OS      : macOS Big Sur
   Xcode   : Xcode 13.1 Build version 13A1030d
```

[image]

Comment: are all the images displayed in xcode app icons and splash screen, i know `cordova resources` leaves some out

Comment: white screen issue exists only in case u got critical errors in app, in case the white screen exists for couple seconds then app start then there is no errors but mis-configration in splash screen plugin...  but in case splash screen keeps white without hiding even after 30 seconds, then for sure its an error and this error could be either from routing so u are not redirecting to a specific page in case url was localhost:port/ or could be related to a plugin u have added to the app without declaring it in providers part...

Comment: @chaos505 yes every images are displayed in xcode.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

The white screen has been cause for issue for many years.

When I had the issue, I searched Google relentlessly and quickly realised no one really knew exactly why it does it but appears to be a lot to do with Apple changing the Splash Screen dimensions with different versions of iOS.

Many have suggested solutions with differing success and my specific problem seemed that my Splash Screen wasn't being dismissed quick enough, leaving the screen white. This is the only solution which worked for me - however I use **Capacitor** and their version of the Splash Screen API so you'll need to modify for your specific needs with Cordova:

```
import { Platform } from "@ionic/angular";
import { SplashScreen } from '@capacitor/splash-screen';

constructor(
   private platform: Platform
){
   this.platform.ready().then(async () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        SplashScreen.hide({
          fadeOutDuration: 1000,
        });
      }, 2000)
    })
}
```

A search for "ionic white splash screen" will present you a vast array of people experiencing the same problem with a multitude of different solutions. I'm afraid you'll probably need to research them and find the one for you.

On a separate note, you should consider updating your version of Ionic from 3 to the current version 5. Although version 6 is due for release imminently.